# Using Jquery in Sharepoint to load a header and footer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery, html

down vote
favorite
I am trying to load a Header and Footer, but ran into a load time issue where it is loading really slow on Sharepoint, tested with WAMP and works fine. I am using

```
$(function(){
   $("#headerFile").load("header.html");
   $("#footerFile").load("footer.html");
});
```

and have tried using document.ready as well. I also want the header and footer to load before the content but if the faster load time makes that less noticeable that is fine.

Comment: Shouldn't you use a full directory path to the header.html and footer.html files?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint uses its own body onload function called `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames` which will collide with your document.ready.

So you can do something like this

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myCustomFunction");
function myCustomFunction() {
   $("#headerFile").load("header.html");
   $("#footerFile").load("footer.html");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always wrap the whole code in a

```
setTimeout(function() {
*your code including header/footer*
}, 1000)
```

The downside is now you have to wait for 1 second before the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.load() is a performance hog, and using it puts you at the mercy of more network overhead. Two suggestions:

- Put the markup directly in the master page. I have to assume you're using a custom master page since you have elements #footerFile and #headerFile. Unless you're instantiating those in jQuery as well.
- Inject the HTML directly using .html().  `$("#footerFile").html("<div>Your HTML</div>");`

If you load the footer dynamically it will have to load after everything else, you you're going to see a delay no matter what you do.

Also you should by using `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames` rather as Veeraj suggests, so +1 to him.